# How can I access my Vue component's data property using a string as it's property name in a v-model directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, v-model, vue-directives

The same way I'm able to access an object's property using bracket notation by utilizing a string naming the property.
For example

```
const foo = {
 "bar[foobar]": "hello world"
}

foo["bar[foobar]"] // "hello world"
```

How can I do the same in a Vue [SFC (Single File Component)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), where I have a data property named `"bar[foobar]"` and want to bind it to an input's value giving the `v-model` directive the value `"bar[foobar]"`?

```
<template>
 <input v-model="bar[foobar]" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data() {
    return {
     "bar[foobar]": "hello world"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried providing the v-model directive as such `v-model='{{ 'bar[foobar]' }}'` but that didnt't work either, or `v-model="this['bar[foobar]']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd just rename the data property but if you can't then you can access it via `$data`:

```html
<input v-model="$data['bar[foobar]']">
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to keep the data property in sync with what's being returned from https://Commercejs.com on validation errors. So if I'd like to watch a property I'd use strings to set method/function property name within the watch object on the instance? `watch: { "bar[foobar]": function(old, new) { } }`

Comment: @john-raymon You can only use simple, dotted paths with `watch`. For anything more complicated you'll need to call the `$watch` method manually. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch